# Relaxation method on a system of two second-order, coupled, non-linear ODEs (boundary value problem)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, relaxations

This is my first question on Stack Exchange - I welcome any suggestions if my approach to asking it does not match the usual conventions around here.

So: I need to solve a system of two second-order, non-linear, coupled differential equations for the functions f and g which depend only on one free variable, i.e. f(x) and g(x). The functions f and g are defined on a finite interval (e.g. [0;10]) and the values of these functions are given at the boundaries (boundary value problem). I need to do this numerically because there is no analytical solution.

I have been scouting a variety of numerical methods and it seems the so-called relaxation method as outlined in ''Numerical Recipes'' by Press et al. might be the way to go. Since I have no numerics background, I may be mistaken in assuming this method is standard knowledge; I will be more than happy to briefly explain what it does if required.

Now, from what I understand, this method works fine for systems of first-order ODEs. In principle, your usual reduction of order does the trick and I can express my system as four coupled first-order ODEs. However, my problem is that I have no boundary conditions for the two additional equations, that is, no BCs for the derivatives of f and g. This is the point where I got stuck.

Questions:
1) Does anyone know if this poses a conceptual problem to the method? How can I circumvent it?
2) Would it be possible to apply the aforementioned relaxation method to the second-order system by 'brute force'?

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT:

The system of first-order ODEs would look like this:

$$ \frac{\partial f(t)}{\partial t} = u(t) \\ 
\frac{\partial u(t)}{\partial t} = a(t,f,g) \\
\frac{\partial g(t)}{\partial t} = v(t) \\
\frac{\partial v(t)}{\partial t} = b(t,f,g,v),$$
where $a$ and $b$ are non-linear functions of their arguments (am not showing them here, but of course I know how they look like). $f(0)$, $g(0)$, $f(10)$ and $g(10)$ would be known values. Should anyone know of a method that can solve these for sure - and I don't mind if it is a built-in method of Mathematica, MATLAB or the likes - I would appreciate any suggestion. Also, thanks to everyone who already commented!

Comment: There are many ways to solve such a problem. You could start with a generic nonlinear BVP solver (e.g. `bvp4c` in Matlab or equivalents in other packages).

Comment: As soon as I can access Matlab I will try that one out, thank you. If you could name some of those other ways of solving it, I'd appreciate it very much. I have attempted to apply the shooting method implemented in Mathematica, but it doesn't seem to do the job - precisely because I don't have boundary conditions in terms of the function derivatives. Relaxation seems to be a way to go - the paper whose results I am trying to recreate quotes the method and the book I point to - but it seems like I can't get it to work. While I try to work on this, I would also be happy to try out other methods.

Comment: I think Mathematica's NDSolve can do nonlinear BVPs as well, I don't know Mathematica but there is a tutorial about it here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem in the setup, for a 4-dimensional first-order system you get 4 slots for boundary conditions, which are filled by the values of $f$ and $g$ at both of the boundaries.

What ever you do numerically, you are solving a non-linear system of equations, so convergence to some solution is only guaranteed from initial points close to that solution. Homotopy continuation methods solve that problem by starting each sub-problem at the solution of the previous one, thus close to the new solution. But it can end in fold points, that is, when following the homotopy curve the process would turn back in the opposite direction of the homotopy variable.

Comment: ''There should be no problem in the setup, for a 4-dimensional first-order system you get 4 slots for boundary conditions, which are filled by the values of f and g at both of the boundaries.'' I agree that it shouldn't be a formal problem; if anything, it seems to be a shortcoming of the particular relaxation method I pointed to. I have a code which implements this relaxation method just fine - it would save me lots of time if there was a way of applying or at least recycling this code to suit my problem. Thanks a lot for your input so far though.

Comment: As soon as you have the first-order formulation, there should be no problem whatsoever in applying the existing code. It should take the ODE and boundary residuals as black-box, internal details such that one variable is the derivative of another should not matter.

Comment: Hi again. Do you happen to be well acquainted with homotopy analysis methods?

Comment: Fleetingly. In many cases it is not really worth it, you often get faster results if you apply a quasi-Newton method to the original problem. Globalization is always a problem, that is, getting into a convergence region if your initial guess is far away from a solution. Homotopy can run into fold points (singular Jacobian) from where you best do a random jump to hopefully some path that goes to the other side. Or add some random perturbation $G$ to the homotopy function, $$H(t,x)=F(x)-(1-t)F(x_0)+t(1-t)G(x)$$

Comment: Hmm, this hits home... I was in fact wondering if there is a smart way of providing an initial guess function. As a method, it seems odd - I want to obtain a solution because I have no idea of how it looks like. Yet I am supposed to provide an initial guess that resembles it...? Weird.

Comment: In many cases the BVP simulates a physics model where the physical intuition tells you what at least the basis solution should look like. Else try to find a similar problem with less terms where the solution can be explicitly obtained or good guesses exist. For instance if you somehow chop away terms to end up with a linear problem, then you can solve the corresponding BVP by hand to get an often good initial guess.

Comment: Okay, that seems reasonable. Thanks!